# Enable compiz on Ubuntu with SiS 771/671

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, compiz

I am running Ubuntu 10.04

I have the following Graphics card info:

```
>lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
```

And I need to enable compiz, even with less moves :), How can I?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: I've Edit the post (10.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there are no 3D Drivers for Sis 771, so while it may be possible to get Compiz up and running, really, the performance is not [upto the mark](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7052597&postcount=147). There's a full thread dedicated to Sis 771 drivers on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=958967&page=38), might want to check it out.